# What impact does SQL transactional Replication have on the transaction log file

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-replication

Im setting up SQL Server Transactional replication that will be continuously running. The distributor for this setup at the server receiving the data

Should i have any concerns  with transaction log file sizes if this is running continuously?

Comment: You could also ask this on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Considerations for Transactional Replication: Transaction Log Space**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151254.aspx)

> ---
>
> For each database that will be
>   published using transactional
>   replication, ensure that the
>   transaction log has enough space
>   allocated. The transaction log of a
>   published database might require more
>   space than the log of an identical
>   unpublished database, because the log
>   records are not truncated until they
>   have been moved to the distribution
>   database.
>
> If the distribution database is
>   unavailable, or if the Log Reader
>   Agent is not running, the transaction
>   log of a publication database
>   continues to grow. The log cannot be
>   truncated past the oldest published
>   transaction that has not been
>   delivered to the distribution
>   database. We recommend that you set
>   the transaction log file to auto grow
>   so that the log can accommodate these
>   circumstances. For more information,
>   see CREATE DATABASE (Transact-SQL) and
>   ALTER DATABASE (Transact-SQL).
>
> Disk Space for the Distribution Database
>
> Ensure that you have enough disk space
>   to store replicated transactions in
>   the distribution database:
>
> If you do not make snapshot files
>   available to Subscribers immediately
>   (which is the default): transactions
>   are stored until they have been
>   replicated to all Subscribers or until
>   the retention period has been reached,
>   whichever is shorter.
>
> If you create a transactional
>   publication and make the snapshot
>   files available to Subscribers
>   immediately: transactions are stored
>   until they have been replicated to all
>   Subscribers or until the Snapshot
>   Agent runs and creates a new snapshot,
>   whichever is longer. If the elapsed
>   time between Snapshot Agent runs is
>   greater than the maximum distribution
>   retention period for the publication,
>   which has a default of 72 hours,
>   transactions older than the retention
>   period are removed from the
>   distribution database. For more
>   information, see Subscription
>   Expiration and Deactivation.